# Linking one domain to another domain with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I'm stuck with htaccess redirect on this case:

I have myapp.com domain where my main website and service runs on. My customers logs into their accounts on myapp.com and use. Now, I am going to provide one of the features on a separate domain, let's assume "goto.com". However, I don't want to build a separate app on goto.com. I just want to redirect all coming requests to goto.com to a php script under myapp.com but this redirection should be in the backend (masked), not a 301 redirection.

Let me clear up:

myapp.com - /var/www/vhosts/myapp.com/httpdocs/index.php

goto.com --> masked redirection --> myapp.com/goto.php?$1

How can I do this with htaccess? Any suggestions?

Comment: Just found that it can be done with redirect [P] (proxy) method:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://myapp.com/public_view/$1 [P]`

What do you think? Is this a good and stable method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Just found that it can be done with redirect [P] (proxy) method: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://myapp.com/public_view/$1 [P]` What do you think? Is this a good and stable method?

That method is fine, it utilizes the [mod_proxy module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html). The only thing I can suggest is adding the `L` flag as well in case you have other rules in your htaccess file.

A limitation with using the `P` flag in an htaccess file is that if a page or request to `http://myapp.com/` redirects, then you're URL address bar will say `http://myapp.com/` instead of your other domain. The only way around this is to use `ProxyPassReverse` but it doesn't work in an htaccess file. You'd need access to vhost config:

```
ProxyPass / http://myapp.com/public_view/
ProxyPassReverse / http://myapp.com/public_view/
```

Additionally, if `http://myapp.com/` sets cookies, you'll need to use the `ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain` and `ProxyPassReverseCookiePath` directives to rewrite those.